# ArrayList not contains string

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

I have the following code:

```
String st = "st1 15";
String sta = "15";
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(5);
arrlist.add("string string string 15");
if (st.contains(sta) && !arrlist.contains(sta)) {
  arrlist.add(st);                      
}
```

I expect that `arrlist.add(st);` will not be executed am I wrong? When i execute the code `if` statement is `true` and `arrlist` is filled with `st`
Any help would be appreciated :) sorry If I'm making a serious mistake, I'm pretty new.

Comment: @Shark Please re-think your comment. Your "that's basically" is wrong.

Comment: @manu `arrlist` *doesn't* contain `15`. It does contain a string that in turn contains `15`.

Comment: So in the end, `arrlist.add(st);` will be executed and you can easily test it by executing your code and printing `arrlist`.

Comment: btw you are missing the semicolons in the first two lines and one bracket at the end of your condition.

Comment: @StefanBeike fixed thanks.

Comment: @manu Could you clarify *why* you think `(st.contains(sta) && !arrlist.contains(sta))` will be false?

Comment: @Biffen I got your answer thanks. Is there a way to achieve what I thought I was doing?

Comment: @Biffen I guess either read `!st.contains(sta)` or thought `arrlist.contains(sta)` will perform a `contains` check on it's elements, instead of `equals`.

Comment: @Tom I thought of the second.

Comment: `arrlist.contains(sta)` will check if the List `arrlist` contains _exactly_ the Object you're passing in using the `equals` implementation. Your list doesn't contain `"15"` (it has a String which contains that substring, but that doesn't matter here) so it returns `false` and since you're inverting that boolean with `!` you'll get `true` instead.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I got that perfectly. So is there a way to do something similar to check if arraylist contains a substring?

Comment: @manu Iterate through it, check whether each element `.contains()`. Preferably put that in a function.

Comment: @Biffen I thought so, I was trying to avoid it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is:

```
String st = "st1 15";
String sta = "15";
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(5);
arrlist.add("string string string 15");

if (st.contains(sta)) {
    boolean shouldAdd = true;
    for ( String val : arrlist ) {
        if (val.contains(sta)) {
            shouldAdd = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( shouldAdd ) {
      arrlist.add(st);                      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (st.contains(sta) && !arrlist.contains(sta))
```

will be `true` because `1 & 1` are always `1`. `Boolean algebra`:

```
a & b
0   0 = false
0   1 = false
1   0 = false
1   1 = true
```

`st` is a `String` that contains the substring "15" what leads to `true` and `arrlist` does not contains `sta` so `!arrlist.contains(sta)` returns also `true`.

as a result of this the whole condition is true.